# Getting the current timestamp for a video with a Discord.js music bot?

Tags: discord.js, ytdl

I am trying to create a music bot with `discord.js` & `ytdl-core`. I would like to display the current timestamp when using a command called `!nowplaying`. However, I am not sure how I get the time. My code:

```js
//bot.queue is a collection, and contains some attributes, like songs (array) and connection (ytdl)
let queue = bot.queue.get(message.guild.id); 

const time = queue.connection.streamTime; //Doesn't work!

//Convert time here, then output

message.channel.send(`Now Playing - ${queue.songs[0].title} - ${time}`);
```

I've tried using `queue.connection.streamTime`, and other methods, but they haven't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `voiceConnection#dispatcher` (it returns a [StreamDispatcher](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher?scrollTo=streamTime)) instead of `voiceConnection`:

```js
//bot.queue is a collection, and contains some attributes, like songs (array) and connection (ytdl)
let queue = bot.queue.get(message.guild.id); 

const time = queue.connection.dispatcher.streamTime; //Doesn't work!

//Convert time here, then output

message.channel.send(`Now Playing - ${queue.songs[0].title} - ${time}`);
```